# laravel session expires if we clear app from android webview

Tags: php, android, laravel-5, webview

I am working on Laravel and android Webview project. I am calling web URL in Android Webview.
Project back-end is in Laravel.

I am facing issue in,
When I was clearing the app it'll every-time asking me to login. I want user to logged in as soon as he/she will not manually click on logout button.

Basically I want user session infinity time.
Please help me to clear this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Session is not longer exists if user leaved. Or You can use Cookies instead of Session (but it is not safe).

I think a better way is to follow Oauth, and to create an access token and a refresh token.

[Oauth2 by Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)